# Using hall sensors to calculate position

Tags: motor, hall-sensor

I have a geared DC motor with hall speed sensors. I want to count signals from the sensor to get position of the motor. Hall sensor has resolution of 12 CPR. Gear ratio is 1:810, which means that I don't really need very precise measurement to get close to the desired position.

But in reality it doesn't work. I run the motor at the same direction trying to get exactly 360 degrees. Sometimes I am close to the position I set, sometimes I am too far (like 300 degrees instead of 360).

The code is simple. I just attached the hall sensor to an interrupt pin and count raises of the signal.

Has anybody tried that? Does anybody knows some obvious problem which causes me to fail such miserably?

Here is the motor I am using:

[image]

Comment: it is possible that some of the interrupts are not getting serviced. please post your code. (minimal code that demonstrates the observed problem)

Comment: The hall sensor may need external circuitry to produce a good signal.  If you put a schematic of the pcb in your question (or hi-res photos of front and back of the pcb if there is no schematic in the documentation from the manufacturer) and post it on electronics.stackexchange you should get a good answer.

Comment: connect just the sensor to your controller. load simple code to control an LED with the sensor, then slowly spin the sensor magnet.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Kons. You said, *"The code is simple. I just attached the hall sensor to an interrupt pin and count raises of the signal."* What code? Where is the code? Are you trying to drive the motor for X number of counts, or are you running the motor at full speed and counting the number of pulses? Have you checked the pulse train with an oscilloscope or similar? Are you seeing variable results under the same loading, or are your angles varying under load or at different speeds? *What troubleshooting have you done?*

Answer (score 1):

Are you running a PID loop to control the motor?  Without a PID loop, the motor is going to be highly dependent on load and will likely stop differently every time.  Also, since the sensor is relative position only, you will need a way to home the motor to be able to know absolute position.

If you need accurate absolute position, you could use a [hall absolute position sensor](http://www.ttelectronics.com/sites/default/files/download-files/Datasheet_NonContactSingleTurn_6120Series.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Looks like my initial problem was had 2 root causes: 1) I should have used both interrupts of the motor hall sensors (one produces some extra signals). 2) Without PID loop it was too inaccurate. I decreased the motor speed and now it looks way much better. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Glad to hear you are making progress.

Comment: Note: A PID loop is pretty easy to do.  One of the biggest questions would be whether you want the PID to control position or error.  That is really dependent on your design.  It sort of sounds like to me that you are looking for positional control.

Comment: @Kons, `one produces some extra signals` ... not "extra signals" .... you need to fully understand what you are dealing with if you want to have success

Comment: @Kons Are trying to decode a quadrature encoder yourself by capturing the edges using interrupts?  If so, there are LOTS of things that can go wrong!  One classic problem is edge jitter where the encoder produces a very fast chain of edges because the encoder stops right on one of the encoder transitions and ends up quickly going back-and-forth across it.  Missing or mishandling the edges thus cause the position to appear to move even though it didn't.

Comment: @markshancock Yes, I decode a quadrature encoder. Now I understand how many glitches I can catch with this. Today, for example, one of my the sensor wires became a little bit loose and positioning became innacurate. The motor moved and stopped but in wrong positions. Fixed that with just putting wires deeper in my breadboard.  And yes, I try to control position.

Comment: @Kons You are going to have to deal with edge jitter of you are not going to get accurate results.  The rate can sometimes be faster than the processor can service interrupts.  Last time I did this, I did it in HW using an FPGA.  You might be able to do it in SW by funneling all the interrupts into a single service routing, read both phases at the same time and put a filter in so that you treat interrupt bursts as a single event.

Comment: @markshancock The motor can do only 5000rpm. With 12 poles of the magnet and 2 sensors it will give 120 000 interrupts per minute, or 2000 interrupts per second. 500us for should be long enough to service my simple handlers. But you're right, the whole thing will be much easier with absolute position hall sensor. Will buy one for experiments. I need to have absolute position in any case.

Comment: @Kons Good that you did the math to make sure you can handle max RPM.  The problem I am mentioning occurs when the motor stops at an encoder transition point and the because of vibration it oscillates back-and-forth across it.  If you are able to service all the edges, it will be a sequence of +1 and -1 that all cancel out, it not you will miss some and the result will be position creep.  Also, your comment "12 poles and 2 sensors" sounds like you are using an resolver rather than an an optical encoder.  I have primarily run into jitter on optical encoders which have much higher counts/rev.

Comment: @Kons, Note: We have found that the Hall Position sensor crosses the 360 point with V<5V and v>0V (what we call the "Hall Hole").
The way we handle that is:
1) During homing, we log the limit values and use those for calibration
2) We point out primary (forward) direction opposite the "Hall Hole" so we generally don't have to deal with it.
There are likely more expensive sensors that don't have this issue; but, we are on a tight budget.